# Integrability of a family of functions, parameterized by the points of the compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness, supremum-and-infimum, uniform-integrability

For any $\theta \in \Theta$, let $g(t;\theta)$ be integrable in $t$ over, say, the half line $\mathbb{R}_+$. Then suppose $\Theta$ is a compact set, then can we say $\sup_{\Theta}g(t;\theta)$ is also integrable?

To me, intuitively speaking it should be but I am having a bit of trouble proving why? If it is not, what are some of the conditions on $g$ such that it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\Theta = [0,1]$.
Consider $g(t,\theta) = 1$ for $t \in [n-1, n)$ where $n = [\theta^{-1}]$ and $g(t,\theta) = 0$ otherwise. Hence, for example $g(t,0)=0$ for all $t$. In this case $sup_{\theta}g(t,\theta)=1$ isn't integrable. According to this scheme, it is easy to make a counterexample with smooth functions $g$.

If $\Theta$ is infinite, then there is a subset $ \{ \theta_m \}$ which is infinite, so we may consider $g(t, \frac{1}{m})$ for $\theta = \theta_m$ and put all other $g(t,\theta) = 0$.

If $\Theta$ is finite then the statement holds true, because  $g(t, \theta_0) \le sup_{\theta}  g(t,\theta) \le \sum_{\theta} g(t,\theta)$.

One more trivial condition:
If $ \int_M^{\infty} \sup_{\theta} g(t,\theta) dt < \infty$ for some $M$ and if $g(t,\theta)$ are unformly bounded then the statement holds true.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. Thanks! I suppose intuitively speaking, if we want $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} g(t;\theta)$ to be integrable, then by the Dominated convergence theorem, if there exists an $f(t)$ such that $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} g(t; \theta) \le f(t)$ for any $t$, (in say, $\mathbb{R}$) and $f(t)$ is integrable, then $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} g(t; \theta)$ is also integrable (by the Dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: @JeffreyKwan In dominated convergence theorem there is convergence in case $n \to \infty$, and here we have situation that is a bit different.